# Find the nth word in a line, and replace it back into the line in different position

Tags: regular-expression, search, replace

I have searched unsuccessfully everywhere for an answer to this question and could not find an acceptable answer.

I am taking a list of table names from a database, and dynamically creating alter statements to change the database name.

What I am getting is something like the following:

```
call_center
catalog_page
catalog_returns
catalog_sales
customer
customer_address
customer_demographics
date_dim
household_demographics
income_band
inventory
item
```

I do a search and replace with:

```
 %s/^/alter table /
```

And end up with the following:

```
alter table call_center$
alter table catalog_page$
alter table catalog_returns$
alter table catalog_sales$
alter table customer$
alter table customer_address$
alter table customer_demographics$
alter table date_dim$
alter table household_demographics$
alter table income_band$
alter table inventory$
alter table item$
```

I run the following:

```
%s/\v(\S\s+)(\S+\s+)(\S+)$/\1\2\3\ rename to tpcds.\3;/
```

and end up with:

```
alter table call_center rename to tpcds.call_center;
alter table catalog_page rename to tpcds.catalog_page;
alter table catalog_returns rename to tpcds.catalog_returns;
alter table catalog_sales rename to tpcds.catalog_sales;
alter table customer rename to tpcds.customer;
alter table customer_address rename to tpcds.customer_address;
alter table customer_demographics rename to tpcds.customer_demographics;
alter table date_dim rename to tpcds.date_dim;
alter table household_demographics rename to tpcds.household_demographics;
alter table income_band rename to tpcds.income_band;
alter table inventory rename to tpcds.inventory;
alter table item rename to tpcds.item;
```

I can shorten this to:

```
%s/\v(\S\s+){1}(\S+)$/\1\2 rename to tpcds.\2;/
```

However, what I was never able to figure out, and need help with, how do you move a word, by its "position/index" to somewhere else in the line? I know how to do this if you are looking a specific word (like cat), but what if the word is always different, but in the same position?

For example, what if I were building select clauses, and wanted to change the following:

```
select cc_call_center_id, cc_name from call_center;
select i_item_id, i_name from item;
```

to:

```
select cc_call_center_id, cc_name from call_center order by cc_call_center_id;
select i_item_id, i_name from item order by i_item_id;
```

How do you select the nth word (in this case, the 2nd) and append it somewhere else in the line (in this case, to the end of the line)?

*BTW, I realize I could just change it to "order by 1", but this is just an example.

Hope this makes sense.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would use `:normal`:

```
:%norm wyiwf;i order by <c-v><c-r>"
```

You can also use a substitution:

```
:%s/\w\+\s\+\(\w\+\).*\zs;/ order by \1;
```

I am using `\zs` to set the start of the match to simply the substitution. If you are having issue with substitutions then I suggest using [traces.vim](https://github.com/markonm/traces.vim) to help give visual feedback.

For more help see:

```
:h :norm
:h :range
:h c_CTRL-R
:h /\zs
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Peter. For the example I provided, this command worked: `%s/\w\+\s\+\(\w\+\).*\zs;/ order by \1;` However, it really doesn't help with how you would index the words. For example, what if I wanted to move the third word and insert it as the next to last word? Or, simply take the third word, and putting it at the end. Changing the number `\1` to `\2` does not work./

Comment: You will have to update the regex pattern. If you are going to do a bunch of crazy X number word, then I would suggest you look into `awk`

Comment: Thanks Peter. What I was hoping to find was some way of doing something similar to: `%s/\v(\S\s+){1}(\S+)$/\1\2 rename to tpcds.\2;/` where I could have several patterns, and restructure the line with something like `\3 \2 \1 \4/`. For example, I want to repeat the first 3 words as a group (let's call it pattern 1), take the 4th word (call it pattern 2), and the remainder of the line (call it pattern 3), and then replace the line with `/\1 \2 \3 \2`. In other words, just copying the third word, and appending it to the same line -- as an example. Can this not be done using Vim?

Comment: With a substitution you would have to craft your capture groups. `:s/\(\w+\s\)\{3\}\(\w\+\)\s.*\zs/ \2/` for you copy 4th word put at the end. or `:norm 3wyiwA <c-v><c-r>"`. If you are doing this with awk: `%!awk '{ print $0, $4}'`. If you wanted to do this in vimscript you would do `:g/^/let a = split(getline('.'), '\s\+')|call setline('.', join(a + [a[3]], ' '))`. You can of course you any programming language of choice to do these manipulations as well, perl/ruby/awk/python/etc. You can use `:!` in Vim to filter through a program.

Comment: Yes, always more than one way to solve a problem. Need vim for down and dirty quick modifications to files, and hoping to learn more. Perl/Python/R are always good options for more detailed, or repeatable processes. Can you provide a line that would be modified by: `:s/\(\w+\s\)\{3\}\(\w\+\)\s.*\zs/ \2/` ? I am not tracking with that command. Thanks for your quick response!

Comment: `:s/\(\w\+\s\)\{3}\(\w\+\)\s.*\zs/ \2/` copies the 4th word to the end of the line. e.g. `foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4 bar` becomes `foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4 bar foo4`

Comment: Thank you! I got it now. I'll blame my slowness on being a Monday. BTW, for the benefit of others, the examples do not work with commas or other special characters.